# How can i make my page fullscreen and stretch it till the end

Tags: html, css, width, screen

I'm relatively new to this, so someone help me understand how can I make my page content stretch to fill all the space and not just align in the center? I want to make it fullscreen. In which part of my code do I need changes?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: auto;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#landing {
    background: #fff;
}

#landing-text {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 40vw;
    height: 50vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

#landing-text h2 {
    color: #888;
}

#landing-image {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/dS-q7-zkD9c);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    flex: 0 1 60vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2rem 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    transition: background 500ms ease;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.11);
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

#header {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

#header h2 {
    border-left: dotted 1px #fff;
    border-right: dotted 1px #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.caption {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    color: #333;
}

footer h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-part .fa {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

ul li a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


/* Screen Sizes 500px and Up */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #landing {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #landing-text {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    #landing-image {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}


/* Screen Sizes 700px and Up */

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .btn {
        padding: 1rem 3rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Acme Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Landing Area -->
        <div id="landing">
            <div id="landing-text">
                <div id="landing-text-inner">
                    <h1>Acme Photography</h1>
                    <h2>Beautiful Natural Photography</h2>
                    <a href="#images" class="btn" id="view-work">
                        View Work
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="landing-image"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="images">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>Our Work</h2>
            </div>

            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo One</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,trees" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Two</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,flowers" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Three</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,animals" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Four</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,clouds" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Five</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
        <p>Email or call us to set up a consult</p>
        <p>Email:
            <strong>contact@acmephotos.test</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Phone:
            <strong>(617) 555-5555</strong>
        </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `max-with` on `main`

```
main {
    /*max-width: 900px;*/
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: auto;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

main {
    /*max-width: 900px;*/
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -30px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#landing {
    background: #fff;
}

#landing-text {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 40vw;
    height: 50vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

#landing-text h2 {
    color: #888;
}

#landing-image {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/dS-q7-zkD9c);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    flex: 0 1 60vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2rem 0 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    transition: background 500ms ease;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.11);
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

#header {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

#header h2 {
    border-left: dotted 1px #fff;
    border-right: dotted 1px #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.caption {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    margin: auto;
    color: #333;
}

footer h3 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-part .fa {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

ul li a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


/* Screen Sizes 500px and Up */

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #landing {
        display: flex;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #landing-text {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    #landing-image {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}


/* Screen Sizes 700px and Up */

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    .btn {
        padding: 1rem 3rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Acme Photography</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Landing Area -->
        <div id="landing">
            <div id="landing-text">
                <div id="landing-text-inner">
                    <h1>Acme Photography</h1>
                    <h2>Beautiful Natural Photography</h2>
                    <a href="#images" class="btn" id="view-work">
                        View Work
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="landing-image"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="images">
            <div id="header">
                <h2>Our Work</h2>
            </div>

            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo One</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,trees" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Two</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,flowers" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Three</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,animals" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Four</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,clouds" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Photo Five</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo, tenetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
        <p>Email or call us to set up a consult</p>
        <p>Email:
            <strong>contact@acmephotos.test</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Phone:
            <strong>(617) 555-5555</strong>
        </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you always use this code at the top of your CSS document.

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The star points to all the elements!

Your page is simply responsive. You can use a framework like Bootstrap. And put the writings and boxes together and the page will be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `width: 100%;` in your CSS if you'd like to stretch the content from the left edge to the right edge of your webpage.
As said by Lalji Tadhani above, remove the `max-width` in the `main` html tag's css because it will only let it stay till 900px and will not allow its contents to stretch till both of the sides.